# Special character in filename

Tags: pdftex, luatex, extended-characters

I have many special characters in a filename e.g., `./CaMKII-8+PP1-32+L-125e-9+N-5+diff-0.1e-12.dat_processed.csv`. I want to write this filename in a footnote. To make matter worse, this filename is stored in a macro e.g., `\edef\fiename\{./CaMKII-8+PP1-32+L-125e-9+N-5+diff-0.1e-12.dat_processed.csv}`.

When I try to print it using `\texttt{\fileName}`, I run into a 'missing $ inserted' issue. If I use `\verb!\fileName!`, it just prints `\fileName` (it's not expanded.)

How to get the filename printed in my pdf?

Comment: `\edef\fileName{\detokenize{./CaMKII-8+PP1-32+L-125e-9+N-5+diff-0.1e-12.dat_processed.csv}}`

Comment: @egreg Worked like a charm. I think you can add it as an answer. It was not easy to find.

Comment: You can also use the \path command supplied by the `url` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file name is stored in a macro, you can exploit `\detokenize`:

```
\newcommand{\fileName}{}% just to see it can be used
\edef\fileName{\detokenize{./CaMKII-8+PP1-32+L-125e-9+N-5+di‌​ff-0.1e-12.dat_proce‌​ssed.csv}}
```

This will have no consequence when `\fileName` is used for reading a file.

Note that you need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for the underscore to print when not in a `\ttfamily` or `\texttt` context. It will print fine with `\texttt{\fileName}`.